# How to get Fiddler to report HTTP connections on a local PC

Tags: fiddler

I have a client and a server and they are both on the local box and they speak web services.  How can I get Fiddler to report these connections?

It only seems to want to report connections to other PCs.

NOTE: I actually found the answer.  http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: Please note, IE9 RC allows Fiddler to capture localhost traffic with no reconfiguration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add a period (.) after localhost or use the machines name for the URL of the site you want to view traffic for in your browser.

For example:

```
http://localhost./foo.html
```

Or:

```
http://mymachinename/foo.html
```

See [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/knownissues.asp) for known documented issues with fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Tab named "Filters" where you can setup a host list to ignore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer but wrong question ;-) He's actually looking to do the opposite-- to show requests that aren't shown by default.